# How to call matlab function/script in ssh?

Tags: matlab, ssh

In a file S.m I store:

```
function s = S(a, b)
    s = a + b;
```

I try to call the function from ssh shell like this:

```
matlab -r -nodisplay "S 3 5" > sum.txt
```

and I get a "not enough arguments in input" error. Can anyone see the reason for that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a matlab program with arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981168/running-a-matlab-program-with-arguments)

Comment: Your error is that the `"S 3 5"` part should come right after `-r`: `matlab -nodisplay -r "S 3 5"`

Comment: Also, `a` and `b` in your function will be strings if you call `S` this way. Use `str2double` to convert them to numbers.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: Maybe write that into an answer so the question can be marked as answered?

Comment: @Argyll: OK, I did.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I upvoted your answer. Btw, do you happen to know starting with what version of matlab this would work? I used to try it with the 2014a version on a windows machine and it never worked for me

Comment: @Argyll: I've done this under Windows way back in the late 90's, with version 5.3. I have not used Windows a whole lot in the last 10 years, but I don't think this has changed. I added the reference to the Windows command line in the answer.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2669790/3181104). It seems i am not the only one who has had issues with running matlab by ssh'ing into a windows machine

Comment: @Argyll: I didn't even know it is possible to SSH into a Windows machine... Windows is not designed for text-only interaction, I'm not surprised of the problems they describe in that answer. I ran MATLAB from from batch scripts locally, not remotely. I've only ever run MATLAB remotely on Solaris and Linux. Sorry I can't be of more help in your situation!

Comment: @CrisLuengo No worries!

Answer (score 1):

The `-r` argument introduces the command to execute. The two cannot be separated by other arguments. That is, you can write

```
matlab -nodisplay -r "S 3 5" > sum.txt
```

or

```
matlab -r "S 3 5" -nodisplay > sum.txt
```

to get MATLAB to run the function `S` with input arguments '3' and '5'. See [the official documentation of the UNIX command `matlab`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlablinux.html) for more information. There is a separate [documentation page for Windows](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlabwindows.html), where different options are allowed, but the `-r` switch should still work.

Do note that the MATLAB statement

```
S 3 5
```

is equivalent to

```
S('3','5')
```

That is, the arguments are seen as strings. Convert them to numbers using the `str2double` function.